# How to navigate over pages for web-scraping without browser automation frameworks

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

here's the url of a site
https://www.enterprise.com/en/car-rental.html?icid=header.reservations.car.rental-_-start.a.res-_-ENUS.NULL

so i wanna webscrape this site in python without browser automation tools.

in the first page the site will have an input field which should be filled in-order to move to the next page.
and i wanna the scrape this 2nd page.

how to do this ?

how to achieve this without any automation frameworks.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://www.enterprise.com/en/car-rental.html?icid=header.reservations.car.rental-_-start.a.res-_-ENUS.NULL"

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36"
}

page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')  # Changed 'html' to 'html.parser'
```

what should i do?
or can we move to other pages without automation frameworks ?

Comment: The same way you ran the first request, you're gonna run a request to get the second page. How is it done? Look at the network tab of the dev tools on that website when moving onto the next page. There you'll see what request was run to get to that second page

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to fetch the first
2. then make another request which contains the form details for which you need to see how the for data is submitted and send it in the same way
3. use the second page url in the response (if present)
4. if url is not there in the response from step 2 then see how they get the url